# Mysql Workbench Error 1452 al insertar datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando la siguiente bases de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el codigo de ello:

```
create table CLIENTES
    (dni char(6)primary key,
    nombre varchar(20));

create table PRESTAMOS
    (id int(6),
    principal int(20),
    plazo_en_meses int(3),
    cliente varchar (20),
    fecha_comienzo date, foreign key(cliente) references CLIENTES (dni));


create table CUENTAS   
    (numero int(15)primary key,
    saldo float(40),
    cliente varchar(20), foreign key(cliente) references CLIENTES(dni));
```

> Al momento de insertar datos en clientes va bien, pero el problema es al insertar con cuentas y prestamos, da el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`empresa`.`cuentas`, CONSTRAINT `cuentas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`dni`))
```

Los datos los estoy insertado de la siguiente manera:

```
insert into CLIENTES values(1235,'Sebastian');

insert into CUENTAS values(1236,20000,'Sebastian');
insert into PRESTAMOS values(1235,1,4,'Sebastian',20-05-01);
```

Comment: Fíjate que las llaves foráneas en `PRESTAMOS` y `CUENTAS` son `CHAR(6)` que de hecho corresponden al campo `dni` (llave primaria) de la tabla `CLIENTES` y no al campo `nombre`. También estás omitiendo la llave primaria de `PRESTAMOS`.

Comment: @BetaM Así es. No he dicho otra cosa ¿o sí?

Comment: Solo lo comenté por que tu enunciado decia que la columna nombre era la llave primaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procura que tus llaves primarias y foráneas sean:

- Del mismo tipo de dato
- De la misma longitud

---

```
create table CLIENTES
    (dni varchar (20) primary key,
    nombre varchar(20)
);

create table PRESTAMOS(
    id int(6),
    principal int(20),
    plazo_en_meses int(3),
    cliente varchar (20),
    fecha_comienzo date, 
    foreign key(cliente) references CLIENTES (dni)
);


create table CUENTAS(
    numero int(15)primary key,
    saldo float(40),
    cliente varchar(20), 
    foreign key(cliente) references CLIENTES(dni)
);
```

Posterior en tus `INSERT` debes:

- Insertar la misma cantidad de valores en función del número de columnas que tengan
- Procura siempre revisar que los valores que ingresas estén en el espacio adecuado ya que cada columna
  tiene un tipo de dato distinto por lo tanto si no se corresponden te dará error
- Los tipos de dato como date deben ir entre comillas

---

```
insert into CLIENTES values(1235,'Sebastian');
insert into PRESTAMOS values(1235,1,4, 1235, "2020-05-01");
insert into CUENTAS values(1236,20000, 1235);
```

**Referencias**

- [tipos de dato en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html)